# has_and_belongs_to_many model creation needed?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have orders and items table. I also have a third table called orders_items. Which I learned on creating from the following link (2nd graph) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.htm

models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :items, through: :item_order
end
```

models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :orders, through: :item_order
end
```

[orders_items] table has the following:

```
integer :order_id
integer :item_id
```

Do I have to create a models/order_item.rb file to add:

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :item
```

If so what is the correct naming format that it should be? 
Would the name for the model file [order_item.rb] correct to distinguish which table it refers to?

models/order_item.rb ??

```
class OrdersItem ??? < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :item
end
```

Comment: Since an order have many items and an item has many orders. Do I add through: :ordersitems after the has_and_belongs_to_many :[table]

Comment: Your associations are not correct! `has_and_belongs_to_many` wont have `through` option.

Comment: @Pavan, yup since no model for the join table are needed, as you stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)**

> The join table should not have a primary key or a model associated
>   with it. You must manually generate the join table with a migration
>   such as this

```
class CreateDevelopersProjectsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :developers_projects, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :developer_id
      t.integer :project_id
    end
  end
end
```

> Specifies a many-to-many relationship with another class. This
>   associates two classes via an intermediate join table. Unless the join
>   table is explicitly specified as an option, it is guessed using the
>   lexical order of the class names. So a join between Developer and
>   Project will give the default join table name of “developers_projects”
>   because “D” precedes “P” alphabetically

In your case the join table name should be `items_orders`.

Comment: alphabetically, I see! So I'll drop the orders_items table and create items_orders instead. And from what I understood, I do not need the models/item_order.rb?

Comment: @lightbots Yes you wont need a model for join table and shouldn't be created.

Answer (score 0):

Your model must be named OrderItem. And you don't need belongs_to in this class. The file name (order_item.rb) is correct.

I think you need this relationship to fulfill your needs, except if orders is an item too

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

and

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: So then I don't need the third table OrderItem? My orders will have many items, and like wise items have many orders do they not? I may be confused.

Comment: This answer is not valid.HABTM join table should't be having a model name.

Comment: Thank you, I figured from @Pavan's answer